Parent view ignore safe area but child view respect safe area
I am building a custom full screen cover that can be dragged down with a gesture like the podcast app.
For the transition modifier with edge as bottom, it uses the bottom edge of the parent view thus if the parent view doesn't ignore the safe area, the removal animation (i.e. sliding down) gets "stuck"/"glitches" at the bottom edge of the screen.
The issue is I want the elements in the full screen cover like text and buttons to respect the safe area except its background.
I am not sure how to fix this. Every single solution on stackoverflow are completely irrelevant since they are suggesting to use the background modifier without taking into account the usage of modifiers like transition with edge as bottom.
struct Tabs: View {
     @State private var showingCover = false

     var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            TabView {
                ...
            }
            
            if showing {
                FullScreenCover(showingCover: $showingCover)
                    .zIndex(1)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea() //I need to set this here so that the bottom edge recognised by the transition modifier would be the very bottom edge of the device. 
    }
}

struct FullScreenCover: View {
    @Binding var showingCover: Bool
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            //Blue color is the background
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            //Other elements like text must respect safe area
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .offset(y: offset)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1)
                .onChanged { value in
                    if value.translation.height > 0 {
                        withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 0.1)) {
                            //Drag cover vertically based on drag gesture
                            offset = value.translation.height
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    if value.predictedEndTranslation.height < 200 {
                        withAnimation(.smooth()) {
                            //Pop cover back fully
                            offset = 0
                        }
                    } else {
                        withAnimation(.smooth()) {
                            //Dismiss cover to the bottom of the screen
                            showingCover = false
                            offset = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}


The solution I came up with after testing various other solutions for a week now, is reading the safe area insets of the parent view of Tabs View (i.e. in my case was ContentView or even the App struct which also works) and then injecting that into the environment.
Then, read the safe area insets from the environment in the FullScreenCover view and reinstate the safe area insets padding in it.
struct SafeAreaInsetsKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: EdgeInsets = EdgeInsets()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var safeAreaInsets: EdgeInsets {
        get { self[SafeAreaInsetsKey.self] }
        set { self[SafeAreaInsetsKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.safeAreaInsets, geo.safeAreaInsets)
        }
    }
}

struct FullScreenCover: View {
    @Environment(\.safeAreaInsets) var safeAreaInsets

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
           //Blue color is the background
           Color.blue
              .ignoresSafeArea()
        
           //Other elements like text must respect safe area
           VStack {
              Text("Hello")
           }
           .padding(safeAreaInsets)
        }
    } 
}

I am happy to here other more native solutions as well.
